# How to get core dump from stopped program (linux)

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I have a program, which was stopped by `kill -STOP`. I want to take a core dump of it without running it (program must be stopped for all time; if it will receive a SIGCONT, it will die without coredump). How can I get a coredump?

Is it possible to keep program in its current state after taking a coredump? It is a very rare situation, and I can't reproduce it, but I must to analyze it.

Thanks

UPDATES: gcore doesn't work. Gdb (even root) can't attach to stopped process (waits forever  on ptrace PTRACE_ATTACH).  Even dd can't read from /proc/99999/mem with good offsets from /proc/99999/maps (error is `No such process`).

If I try to attach gdb to process and send a SIGCONT to stopped process, I got

```
path... linux-nat.c:####: internal-error: linux_nat_attach: Assertion `pid == GET_PID (inferior_ptid) && WIFSTOPPED (status) && WSTOPSIG (status) == SIGSTOP' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

If i go to the gdb and save a core, it will be corrupted. "Failed to read a valid object file image from memory."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach to the current process with `gdb` and issue the `generate-core-file` command.

Or you can run `gcore` and supply the process id as a parameter.

Comment: can I detach from process without starting it? (I want it to be stopped after detach)

Comment: Yea, you don't have to start it.  If you just want the core file though, `gcore` is the easiest thing so you don't mess with the existing process at all.

Comment: dd: seek..ok;  
read(0, buf, 1)                   = -1 ESRCH (No such process)

Answer (score 0):

Send the process an ABRT signal while it is stopped, then restart it with CONT. It will dump core and abort.

If restarting the process it is not an option for some reason, you can try to examine the pseudofile /proc/[pid]/mem, but it is not in core format, so it is less useable.

Comment: To dump a proc/pid/mem I should use maps from proc/pid/mem and just read a mapped regions?

Comment: ABRT will not work, because I think this process have ulimit -c = 0